# listView multiple textview shown with secific order

Tags: android

As shown in the picture(desired layout), in the right pane of activity I need to create a listview with two textview. data is coming from webservice. When textview of years populate one time against that the other textview (ie pastpapers) will populate multiple times as there will be multiple pastpapars against one year. i don't know how to set this in adapter. I have created xml and done all the coding. but i am unable to set view in adapter. wrong view what i have set is also shown in image(wrong layout which i m getting)

[desired layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8wVP.jpg)

[wrong layout which i m getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yV5bo.png)

Comment: Post your XML file.

Comment: Try adding `TextView` dynamically to display pastpapers data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pinned section listview for this.
You have to create separate layouts for your header(year) and data(pastpapers), separate holders for both of them and set data according to viewType(i.e. header or data).
You can use library, take a look.
https://github.com/beworker/pinned-section-listview[enter link description here](https://github.com/beworker/pinned-section-listview)